# Is there a way in dialogflow, to retain chat history of a session after reloading the web page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, dialogflow-es, sessionid

I build a chatbot using expressjs, reactjs and dialogflow. What I want to do is, the chat history to be remained when the page is refreshed. Is there a way to do that? (Might be using sessionID?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a way to do this with just a few lines of code

var messageList = document.querySelector('df-messenger')
.shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat')
.shadowRoot.querySelector('df-message-list').shadowRoot.querySelector('#messageList');

..

then save the contents of the messageList to a localStorage object in the browser then on page load just load it in to the messageList  element

...

on new message received event

window.localStorage.setItem('chatBotHistory', messageList.innerHTML);

...

onload event of new page

document.querySelector('df-messenger')
.shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat')
.shadowRoot.querySelector('df-message-list').shadowRoot.querySelector('#messageList').innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('chatBotHistory');